# oauth , python and google  API?

Tags: python, api, oauth-2.0

Best way to authentiacte google API using Python?

1) oauth
2) AuthSub

Is there any tutorials for oauth2.o + python + google

Answer (score 1):

You can try: https://bitbucket.org/smartproject/oauth2python

It is well tested and documented library. It runs smoothly on google app engine.

Demo that connects with Google and Facebook: http://esmeoauth.appspot.com/

Answer (score 0):

why you would write full separate code in python ? there is already a module of python which is really easy and useful
http://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/
use that module it's quick and reliable.

Comment: Or http://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/ depending on what APIs you're interacting with.